# pandoc md to .docx: Sections with different number of columns

Tags: ms-word, markdown, pandoc

I wish to generate a .docx file from markdown using pandoc.

My document ends with a bibliography in a References section, which I wish to set in two columns, with the main text occupying a single column.

```
# Example document

This text should occupy a single column

## References

Text after this point should occupy two columns
```

I'm using a [Word template](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/use-columns-adjust-margins-and-do-more-in-markdown-with-these-simple-pandoc-commands-adb4c19f9f35) to format my document's styles, but can't work out how to include a section break, nor how to inherit section properties from the reference .docx.